# Extract specific keywords from XML file with bash script

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have an XML file containing some entries characterized by specific kaywords.
I need to run a for loop on the entries, extract two different keywords for each for them to be used in the for loop as variables.

Here is an example of list.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<responses type="C-FIND">
  <data-set xfer="1.2.840.10008.1.2.1" name="Little Endian Explicit">
    <element tag="0008,0005" vr="CS" vm="1" len="10" name="SpecificCharacterSet">ISO_IR 192</element>
    <element tag="0008,0052" vr="CS" vm="1" len="6" name="QueryRetrieveLevel">STUDY</element>
    <element tag="0008,0054" vr="AE" vm="1" len="8" name="RetrieveAETitle">PLATONE</element>
    <element tag="0010,0010" vr="PN" vm="1" len="16" name="PatientName">Anon^1600373003</element>
    <element tag="0020,000d" vr="UI" vm="1" len="42" name="StudyInstanceUID">1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1</element>
  </data-set>
  <data-set xfer="1.2.840.10008.1.2.1" name="Little Endian Explicit">
    <element tag="0008,0005" vr="CS" vm="1" len="10" name="SpecificCharacterSet">ISO_IR 192</element>
    <element tag="0008,0052" vr="CS" vm="1" len="6" name="QueryRetrieveLevel">STUDY</element>
    <element tag="0008,0054" vr="AE" vm="1" len="8" name="RetrieveAETitle">PLATONE</element>
    <element tag="0010,0010" vr="PN" vm="1" len="16" name="PatientName">Anon^1599844862</element>
    <element tag="0020,000d" vr="UI" vm="1" len="42" name="StudyInstanceUID">1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1</element>
  </data-set>
</responses>
```

I need to extract the keywords "PatientName" and "StudyInstanceUID".
I tried to use something like this:

```
grep -A2 -i "PatientName" list.xml | while read -r string ; do
    PatientName="$(echo $string | grep -i "PatientName" | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1)"
    StudyInstanceUID="$(echo $string | grep -i "StudyInstanceUID" | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1)"
    echo "$PatientName"
    echo "$StudyInstanceUID"
done
```

The problem is that I obtain a lot of empty rows!
What's the problem?

[EDIT]
What I would like to obtain from this example is something like this:

```
Anon^1600373003
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1
Anon^1599844862
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1
```

Thanks so much.

Ivan

Comment: Use a dedicated tool like xmllint

Comment: echo was just an example, I need to implement it in a bash script to perform other actions using the keywords.

Comment: @I.Iudice - Its unclear what you mean when you say _"I need to extract the keywords "PatientName" and "StudyInstanceUID""_. What are you actually trying to achieve? Is it to **A)** Assign e.g. `Anon^1600373003`, and `Anon^1599844862` to the `PatientName` variable, and similarly assign  `1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1` and `1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1` to the `StudyInstanceUID` variable. **B)** Or, just print (echo) the results to the console like what you have shown? **3)** Or something else?

Comment: I've been trying to achieve A), I have to use those variables to run signal processing algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Raman alluded to in the comment, using a XML-aware tool to parse XML data is probably your best bet especially if some of your XML may not be as formatted as displayed in the question (eg, everything on one long line).

Assumptions:

- you can confirm all of your data will be formatted as like the samples in the question (ie, each element is on a separate line)
- the search strings `PatientName` and `StudyInstanceUID` do not show up in larger strings (eg, `LastPatientName` or `PreviousStudyInstanceUID`)
- the `PatientName` element is always listed before the `StudyInstanceUID` element

One `awk` solution which eliminates the need for all of the sub-process calls to `echo`, `grep` and `cut`:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '                                    # define input field separators as "<" and ">"
/PatientName/ || /StudyInstanceUID/ { print $3 }  # if we find one of our search strings then print field #3
' list.xml
```

The same as a one-liner, sans comments:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '/PatientName/ || /StudyInstanceUID/ { print $3 }' list.xml
```

The above generates:

```
Anon^1600373003
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1
Anon^1599844862
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1
```

---

As for capturing the output into variables (eg, within a `while` loop), we can make some small changes, eg:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '
/PatientName/      { pn=$3 }                      # store field #3 in variable "pn"
/StudyInstanceUID/ { printf "%s %s\n", pn, $3 }   # print data to stdout
' list.xml
```

This will generate:

```
Anon^1600373003 1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1
Anon^1599844862 1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1
```

Feeding this into a `while` loop:

```
while read -r PatientName StudyInstanceUID
do
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "PatientName:      ${PatientName}"
    echo "StudyInstanceUID: ${StudyInstanceUID}"
done < <(awk -F'[<>]' ' /PatientName/ { pn=$3 } /StudyInstanceUID/ { printf "%s %s\n", pn, $3 } ' list.xml)
```

And this generates:

```
+++++++++++++++++++
PatientName:      Anon^1600373003
StudyInstanceUID: 1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1
+++++++++++++++++++
PatientName:      Anon^1599844862
StudyInstanceUID: 1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1
```

Comment: I followed your advice; I substituted awk line with xmlstartlet pipe, and it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
grep -A2 -i "PatientName" list.xml
```

returns multiple lines:

```
    <element tag="0010,0010" vr="PN" vm="1" len="16" name="PatientName">Anon^1600373003</element>
    <element tag="0020,000d" vr="UI" vm="1" len="42" name="StudyInstanceUID">1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1</element>
  </data-set>
--
    <element tag="0010,0010" vr="PN" vm="1" len="16" name="PatientName">Anon^1599844862</element>
    <element tag="0020,000d" vr="UI" vm="1" len="42" name="StudyInstanceUID">1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1</element>
  </data-set>
```

so your `while`, read this output line by line. The result you get is correct because on line:

```
<element tag="0010,0010" vr="PN" vm="1" len="16" name="PatientName">Anon^1600373003</element>
```

`StudyInstanceUID` is not present and your variable will be empty.

In order to get the desired result, try this:

```
grep -A1 -i "PatientName" list.xml | while read -r string ; do
    PatientName="$(echo $string | grep -i "PatientName" | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1)"
    read string
    StudyInstanceUID="$(echo $string | grep -i "StudyInstanceUID" | cut -d ">" -f 2 | cut -d "<" -f 1)"
    echo "$PatientName"
    echo "$StudyInstanceUID"
    read string
done
```

Using `read string` you will get next line, but becareful, this works if lines are in that order.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` and `sed` are not designed to process XML. Please use a dedicated tool instead. I can recommend [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

**Stdout:**

```
$ xidel -s list.xml -e '
  //data-set/(
    element[@name="PatientName"],
    element[@name="StudyInstanceUID"]
  )
'
Anon^1600373003
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1
Anon^1599844862
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1
```

**Variables:**

```
$ xidel -s list.xml -e '
  //data-set/(
    eval(x"{concat("pn",position())}:=element[@name=""PatientName""]")[0],
    eval(x"{concat("si",position())}:=element[@name=""StudyInstanceUID""]")[0]
  )
'
pn1 := Anon^1600373003
si1 := 1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1
pn2 := Anon^1599844862
si2 := 1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1
```

These are internal variables that are just printed to stdout. Use `--output-format=bash` and Bash's built-in `eval` command to convert them to shell variables.

```
$ eval $(xidel -s list.xml -e '
  //data-set/(
    eval(x"{concat("pn",position())}:=element[@name=""PatientName""]")[0],
    eval(x"{concat("si",position())}:=element[@name=""StudyInstanceUID""]")[0]
  )
' --output-format=bash)

$ printf '%s\n' $pn1 $si1 $pn2 $si2
Anon^1600373003
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20181217085753.1484038.1
Anon^1599844862
1.3.76.13.99972.2.20180925142630.1456727.1
```